Получение запросов callback с использованием InlineKeyboard
Я бы хотел узнать.
К примеру у меня в коде есть InlineKeyboard, который отдает разные callback при нажатии на кнопки
Как избежать бесконечных if else, когда человек нажимает на клавиатуру, что бы отследить какое дейтсвие нужно сделать программе
Например в Asp.Net есть атрибуты, ты изначально вводишь [HTTPGET], код сам понимает что ему идет get запрос, он не делает проверки, это гет или пост или пут и тд
Как реализовать код без проверок if else?
Мне бы просто узнать куда копать. Делать свои атрибуты, сделать маршрутизацию? Рад любой помощи

Куда копать - паттерн конечный автомат, делаете состояния с нужной логикой, ну а далее задаете и сохраняете состояние, готово.
